# Having issue with JQuery Lightbox code

Tags: jquery, html, css, lightbox

JQuery lightbox code not working, have looked at it several times and read docs, still can't find issues, any help appreciated, thank you. I am a novice. This is for a bootstrap framework website.

```
enter code here <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../docs-assets/ico/favicon.png">

<title>Blank Template for Bootstrap</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-lightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="new.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

```
      <!--Start Of Lightbox Code-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <div id="demoLightbox" class="lightbox hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="lightbox-content">
                    <img src="img/1.jpg">
                    <div class="lightbox-caption">
                        <p>Image Caption</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a data-toggle="lightbox" href="#demoLightbox" class="span2">
                <img src="img/1.png">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--End Of LIghtbox Code-->

</div>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-lightbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Going through your lines of codes , it seems alright. But then i realized the `<script>` include order. `Lightbox` is extension of mainframe `bootstrap library` and which implies that it has a lots of dependencies with the `bootstrap`.

So you need to change the order to something like this ,

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-lightbox.min.js"></script>
```

#### And here is the [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WwMFD/40/) and Here is your [Non-working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WwMFD/41/) with the order maintained.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately that suggestion did not work, the only thing that happens is the dark overlay on the document, no image box opens at all, so still need help with this someone please and thank you.

Comment: :D , Ah !! in that case remove `hide fade` class from the 'demoLightbox' div , and Bam you will see it.